# Why didn't I receive a notification?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

The answer to the question I asked was edited by the answerer but I didn't receive any notification. This is a feature that shouldn't be omitted, after-all, the answers to questions are the reason why we are all here.

Comment: See also: [Lack of notification](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/lack-of-notification). An answer there contains a link to a [feature request at meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97740/optional-notification-on-an-edit-to-an-answer).

Answer (score 3):

First: I took a look at the question that you asked and that I assume that you are referring to. An aanswer was given, then you asked for a picture and I would think that you would have expected (or hoped for) the answer to be edited. So I am not sure that I understand how a notification would have benefited much.

Second: That said, I would not oppose if this did become an option that could be selected, but I do not think that this should be implemented as default for everyone. Some thoughts:

- This could actually lead to a lot of notifications. It is not unusual to see several answers to a question and have each answer be edited several times.
- I don't think that it is too hard to keep an eye on the answers given until one satisfies you. With the questions that I have asked, I usually keep an eye on any updates for sometime after having accepted an answer.
- It is already possibly to notify a person by using the @username. So maybe the encouragement should simply be that if an answerer edits an answer after days have past, they should/could use @OP.

Comment: What about the situation where I am already satisfied, but the answerer added something that vastly improved the quality of his answer. How do I, the asker benefit from that?

Comment: @user2798694: Then it might be nice for you have the option of getting a notification. But, as mentioned, if you turn on this type of notification for everyone, then my guess is that this would lead to too many notifications. Since most edits (to my knowledge) happen early, then you could of course just say that the type of notification should only show up after a certain time limit.