# Is it possible to notify when some user edit his/her answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

It is not uncommon to edit old answers by adding more details among many users.
Several times I have noted that when someone edit his or her answer to a my question, it is not inform to me.
Can we add some feature to overcome this issue?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Some indication is given when a *favorited* Question is edited or has an answer added or edited.  Unfortunately the user has to look at their Activity page, and inspect the line of "tabs" that begins with *summary* (just below the Reputation, Badges, and Impact boxes).  The numbers that appear (if any) next to *favorites* indicate how many of these Questions have new activity.

Comment: This has been fixed. One can now Follow posts, and by doing this one will be receiving notification(s) for each and every action in the post.

Comment: Some related posts on [math.meta.se]: [Why didn't I receive a notification?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11106) and [Lack of notification](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2572). On [meta.se]: [Optional notification on an edit to an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97740).

Comment: You get a notification if you [follow](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/follow-post/info) an answer. But following all answers to your questions would probably be rather cumbersome workaround.